# MigrationBuilder.InsertData not working in old migration on new machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code in a Code First migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
   migrationBuilder.InsertData("Programs"
   , new [] { "Column1", "Column2" }
   , new [] { "value1", "value2" });
}
```

I added these by hand, so there is no corresponding entry in the Designer files (and there is no model defined in code).
These migrations all worked at some point, but when trying to get the project to run on a new computer, I'm greeted with the following error when running Update-Database

> There is no entity type mapped to the table 'Programs' which is used
> in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the
> model, or specify the column types in the data operation.

I tried adding the column types, which worked, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without altering the migrations, as I'll have to go through a bunch and manually change them to something different than what was used on other machines (and some of the columns are DateTimes, which EFCore doesn't seem to recognize, so I had to input them as string).

VS2022 (on all machines).
EFCore 6 being used, but probably wasn't used to initially create these migrations.

Thank you for any help.